# QTCreator "Start debugging" hangs in WSL Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: debugging, qt-creator, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, for the Windows Subsystem For Linux (WSL).

I installed a large number of packages, including `ubuntu-desktop`, `build-essential`, `qtcreator` and a number of others.

QTCreator itself seems to work fine for the most part. I can compile projects and run them in both Debug and Release just fine.

However, when I try to enter "Start Debugging" in a debug release, it hangs indefinitely. Once started, "stop debugging" does not work anymore, and the only fix is to completely kill QTCreator and restart it. Same thing happens on a coworkers machine.

Is this a known limitation of WSL?

Emacs + GDB seems to fine for debugging, so it shouldn't be an issue with GDB which I believe QTCreator uses under the hood. (Though for various reasons, I still want QTCreator's debugger specifically)

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- GDB is version `(Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git`
- Windows 10 is build 1909
- QTCreator is version 4.5.2, based on QT 5.9.5
- Using VcXsrv Windows X Server

Comment: did you try disabling "Run in terminal" in Project > Build&Run > YourKit > Run?
Works for me on QtCreator version 4.12.0

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks.